# sagemath: Convert Fractions in Dictionaries in a list to Decimals for matplotlib

Tags: list, dictionary, python-2.7, sage

```
eng3 = [solve(eng==(k-1)*md*Vm^2/(2*Patm*Vc*(Pc-Pc^(1/k))),Vc,solution_dict=1) for Pc in  xrange(2,10)]
```

I'm trying to automate the process of some efficiency graphs in sage mathematics, and I've got this formula. `Matplotlib.pyplot` wants a list of values. I either get a dictionary in a list as described below, or a list in the form of:

```
List:
[[Vc == (5231100000/35166511904977)], [Vc == (111907000000/1692075843832947)], [Vc == (364112000000/8911538005781703)], [Vc == (753818000000/25992803547821049)], [Vc == (138358000000/6222694018119437)], [Vc == (659020000/36808310575981)], [Vc == (25902500000/1736640592770261)], [Vc == (59144000000/4642920082445667)]]

Dictionary:    
[[{Vc: 1743700000/105499535714931}], [{Vc: 319775000/43516062236099}], [{Vc:  34670000000/7636845816518169}], [{Vc: 41083500000/12749600170083701}], [{Vc: 1703720000/689628024927753}], [{Vc: 25247000000/12691109152994019}], [{Vc: 44767000000/27012747987604137}], [{Vc: 5993300000/4234372317920577}]]
```

I want to take those fractions, convert them in to their numerical approximations, and create a list with those values in sage math[python]. The `n()` function will convert fractions to decimals, but I'm not sure how to isolate the values to feed it to `n()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comes from `solve`, but the question is really a pure Python one.  To get each of these, if the list is called `Vlist`, you could do

```
[v[0].rhs().n() for v in Vlist]
```

and for the dictionary the somewhat more cumbersome

```
[v[0].values()[0].n() for v in Vlist]
```

This construction is known as a "list comprehension". These assume that you really have single solutions to each!  If the format is different (e.g., if you get something like `Vc == 2*Vc^2`) then you'd have to be more clever.

Background - apparently [this ask.sagemath.org question](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/1723/whats-wrong-with-this) is related.

Comment: I posted that other one on sagemath. Ashamed to say I forgot about the difference between = and ==. I'm kinda new to python, but not to math. The formulas relate to optimum efficiency values for a pneumatic air cannon. It'll always give fractions in my current arrangement. It's a side engineering project I've been working on. Thanks again